# how to hide content type from anonymous users in orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I'm creating a simple contact form module in orchard. I don't want the submission to be visible from the outside once it is submitted. eg it should not be accessible from Contents/Item/Display/78

What is the best way to have the items viewable, but only on or via the admin screens?

Ways that have not worked so far:

- on off security per editing anonymous role (shown below). The content type has 'View' effectively enabled.

[image: the test content type is enabled via effective]

- permissions per item: I don't want to set permissions on an item level so I don think the Orchard.ContentPermissions module is applicable

How to make content type viewable from admin screen only?

Comment: It is your own module? So you created a custom content part and type?

Comment: @devqon yep. I'm creatating the content type and parts in code with ContentParts, Handlers, etc

Comment: Using Custom Forms would be easier in this situation (a simple contact form). It has a separate AdminUI Menu Item for Submissions. Marking items as draftable as well I believe keeps it out of the front-end from viewing.

Comment: @REMSEQ Making items draftable isn't quite the right solution because I don't want to allow the admin to accidentally publish a submission. When the form is in edit mode, it has publish button next to the save.

Answer (score 0):

In Users > Roles > Anonymous find the "Contents Feature" section. Uncheck "view all content" and hit save. The effective boxes should be unchecked and you will have full control over your permissions.